# Wxpython - setting background color of a listctrl of a CELL, not of the entire row

Tags: python, wxpython

Is it possible to set the background color of a cell in a wxpython listctrl object? I have found SetItemTextColour() and the SetItemBackgroundColour() but both only change the colors for the entire row.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to switch to an **UltimateListCtrl**  to achieve your goals, take a look in the [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php) for an example of how to accomplish your goals their sample has single-celled background adjustments. You can also checkout the AGW [home page](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/ultimatelistctrl_module.html) for more information and updated version.

from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ulc

self.uListCtrl = ulc.UltimateListCtrl(self, -1, agwStyle=ulc.ULC_REPORT | ulc.ULC_SINGLE_SEL)

Comment: I agree. I'm pretty sure the native widgets do not support just changing the color of one cell.